# Dynamic point shifting based on bearing and elevation surface

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler, qgis-expression

I'm currently working on a graphical model (for planning centre pivot irrigation locations) that moves points iteratively based on a given span length, bearing and span number. All spans are initially concentric, with the goal of accounting for overland differences.

I need to determine the difference between Span 2 and Span 1's elevation at each bearing. From this I can find the 'actual SpanLength' vale for span 1, which I will make an x y shift toward a centroid accordingly for all points above a span 1 value (ie. Spans 2, 3 and onward will all be shifted by this 'actual span 1 length'.)

Each Point will then resample the DEM, creating new 'Elevation' values and this same process will then need to occur for Span 3 and span 2's elevation at each bearing.

I'm just wondering the correct syntax to generate this Span 2-Span1 elevation at each given Bearing (0-359)

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see your attempts for the required expression. Or you could provide a "pseudo code" of what you need exactly. I tried something like this: `if(
  attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer_name, $id + 1), 'Elevation'),
  round(attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer_name, $id + 1), 'Elevation') - attribute($currentfeature, 'Elevation'), 2),
  round(attribute(get_feature_by_id(@layer_name, 0), 'Elevation') - attribute($currentfeature, 'Elevation'), 2)
)`,  but I'm not sure if that's what you need. At least it shows how to access attributes of the "next feature".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it using the field calculator:

```
with_variable(
    'current_bearing',
    "Bearing",
    array_get(
        aggregate(
            @layer_name,
            'array_agg',
            "Elevation",
            "Bearing" = @current_bearing AND "Span" = 2
        ),
        0
    )
)

-

with_variable(
    'current_bearing',
    "Bearing",
    array_get(
        aggregate(
            @layer_name,
            'array_agg',
            "Elevation",
            "Bearing" = @current_bearing AND "Span" = 1
        ),
        0
    )
)
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked very well.